# How to run Selenium tests parallelly in one machine

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-grid

I have two test suites configured in build.gradle and i am using selenium-server-standalone-2.1.0.jar. How can i make use of selenium-grid to run selenium tests parallel. Is it possible to run two different test suites at a time?